# NRE when using Html.Encode within @helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When invoking this helper from another cshtml I get a Null Pointer Exception on the encode line.

```
@helper ShowDefinitionText(String text)
{    
    <b>Definition:</b>
    <p>
    @Html.Encode("dogs")
    </p>
}
```

Is it not legal to use an Html.* from within a helper?

Thanks.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/dont-call-htmlencode-in-razor.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass it as argument:

```
@helper ShowDefinitionText(String text, HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{    
    <b>Definition:</b>
    <p>
        @htmlHelper.Encode("dogs")
    </p>
}
```

and when invoking the helper from the view provide a valid instance:

```
@ShowDefinitionText("some text", Html)
```

Also if you are only going to HTML encode you probably don't need a helper as the `@` Razor operator already does this:

```
@helper ShowDefinitionText(String text)
{    
    <b>Definition:</b>
    <p>
        @text
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why does `@Html.Encode(Model.Text)` work outside the context of a helper but not inside the helper?

Comment: @Dejas: How are you calling the helper?

Comment: @SLaks `@HtmlHelpers.ShowDefinitionText("cats");`